# Java capitalizing first letter of every word in string array

Tags: java, arrays

Excuse the brevity, currently on mobile.

I have a string array of values **ABC, DEF, GHI** that I would like to change to capitalized form: **Abc, Def, Ghi**

My code looks something like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;

....

final String[] split = stringToConvert.split(", ");

final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for ( String s : split) {
   //s = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(s.toLowerCase());

  if (sb.length() > 0) {
    sb.append(", ");
  }
  sb.append(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(s.toLowerCase()));
}

return sb.toString();
```

The first value is always abc, but the second and following ones are correct, e.g. Def, Ghi. I don't know why the first value stays lowercase.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ca you post the code in `WordUtils.capitalizeFully()`

Comment: No because it's part of apache commons-lang3

Comment: yes just now checked

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. You don't even need to "lowercase" the string... WordUtils ought to do that by itself. What does your test-case look like?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code into a unit test and got AbcDefGhi on `sb.toString()`, which is what was expected.

Comment: Well currently my output is: abc, Def, Ghi and I don't understand why the first value stays lowercase

Comment: it is impossible to get "abc, Def, Ghi" because you're calling `sb.append(s)` -- not anything with commas or spaces. Please post your *actual* code. Because what you've posted, works.

Comment: Also if you're trying to change the values *in the array*, where do you assign the values to the array? eg where do you put the capitalized string back into `stringToSplit`?

Comment: Just added my code, it doesn't work, my output is always abc, Def, Ghi

Comment: Aside: Not that it should matter for this particular case, but the `lang3.text.WordUtils` is deprecated, and the replacement code is in `commons.text.WordUtils`.

Comment: Also an aside: in the `capitalizeFully()` method, it does a `.toLowerCase()`, so the `s.toLowerCase()` is redundant.

Comment: @KevinO What's weird is if I remove my toLowerCase() the string values stay capitalized

Comment: Well, let's ask some other questions: what version of the library are you using? And is there anything about the encoding of the input that could be off? Because when I do `sb.append(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(s));` it works as expected.

Comment: @KevinO for me too, but only for the second value in the array. The first one stays all lowercase: abc

Comment: @KevinO apache.commons.lang version 2.6

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to single-step through this code? It's so simple you could have done that more quickly than posting this question on SO.

Comment: I don't believe 2.6 is possible with the import for `lang3`. I'm pretty sure they restarted their version numbering.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz and yes and the debugger shows that here it's set to lowercase (WordUtils.capitalizeFully(s.toLowerCase() and never back to capital. The second iteration of the loop works

Comment: @MJ95 Try "step into" and look a the `WordUtils.capitalizeFully` code as its executing. Can't see the source? Try downloading it. It's completely open-source and freely-downloadable. Make sure you get the same source version as the binary version you are actually using.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Thanks!!! I realized the first character was actually a [ from the array, thus for the first one the second char a was never capitalized

Answer (score 2):

Check your code again.

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

for (String str : new String[]{"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"})
    buf.append(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(str.toLowerCase()));

System.out.println(buf);
```

Prints `AbcDefGhi`, as expected.

It could be simplier, if you use `Stream`:

```
String res = Stream.of("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")
        .map(WordUtils::capitalizeFully)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));    // if you want to split words with comma
```

Comment: Tried this, see above, it's actually comma separated, nonetheless still get abc, Def, Ghi

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.

May I however suggest using a stream instead?

```
String concatenatedString = Arrays.stream(array)
    .map(WordUtils::capitalizeFully)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Which, with appropriate static imports fits well on one line without losing readability:

```
String concatenatedString = stream(array).map(WordUtils::capitalizeFully).collect(joining());
```

Note that `joining()` uses a `StringBuilder` iternally, so you don't need to worry about performance here. Also, `joining()` allows you to choose which string you want to delimit the content of the stream with, in this case I chose an empty string, which would result in *AbcDefGhi*.

Comment: But strangely enough, my code doesn't work. I would like to understand why

Comment: The problem is not the array-traversal. Something else isn't working. Why are you suggesting the OP change their code to something even more complicated which may also still not work? The OP (presumably) understands their existing loop, and just has a question about the capitalization part.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I don't agree that it is more complicated. I suggested an approach where it is very hard to do wrong. But I agree that the trouble the OP has is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

This should do :

```
String[] stringToSplit = {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(String s: stringToSplit) {
   sb.append(s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Update: I'm tired...

The first character was actually a [ from the array instead of "a", thus the a was never capitalized

Thanks all, and sorry for wasting your time